# Accessing Hibernate Session from EJB using EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3

Is it possible to obtain the Hibernate Session object from the EntityManager? I want to access some hibernate specific API...

I already tried something like:

```
org.hibernate.Session hSession =
   ( (EntityManagerImpl) em.getDelegate() ).getSession();
```

but as soon as I invoke a method in the EJB I get "A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB" with a NullPointerException

I use glassfish 3.0.1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335570/accessing-hibernate-session-from-ejb-using-entitymanager/4335608#4335608) and [partenon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335570/accessing-hibernate-session-from-ejb-using-entitymanager/4335600#4335600) are correct, but:

In JPA 2, the preferred mechanism is [entityManager.unwrap(class)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29)

```
HibernateEntityManager hem = em.unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);
Session session = hem.getSession();
```

I think your exception is caused because you are trying to cast to an implementation class (perhaps you were dealing with a JDK proxy). Cast to an interface, and everything should be fine (in the JPA 2 version, no casting is needed).

Comment: even better as explained by @Pascal Thivent in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493495/getting-database-connection-in-pure-jpa-setup you can use `em.unwrap(Session.class)` direcly.

Answer (score 12):

From Hibernate EntityManager docs, the preferred way of doing it is:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```

Answer (score 6):

As simple as:

```
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```

Answer (score 6):

If your `EntityManager` is properly injected (using `@PersistenceContext`) and is not null, then the following should work:

```
org.hibernate.Session hSession = (Session) em.getDelegate();
```