# JPA & Criteria API - Select only specific columns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I would like to select only specific columns (ex. `SELECT a FROM b`). I have a generic DAO and what I came up with is:

```
public List<T> getAll(boolean idAndVersionOnly) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(entityClazz);
    Root<T> root = criteria.from(entityClazz);
    if (idAndVersionOnly) {
        criteria.select(root.get("ID").get("VERSION")); // HERE IS ERROR
    } else {
        criteria.select(root);
    }
    return manager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

And the error is:
`The method select(Selection<? extends T>) in the type CriteriaQuery<T> is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>)`. How should I change that? I want to get a type `T` object that has only `ID` and `VERSION` fields, and all others are `null`.

Type `T` extends `AbstractEntity` which has those 2 fields.

`entityClazz` is `T.class`.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

One of the JPA ways for getting only particular columns is to ask for a [Tuple](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) object.

In your case you would need to write something like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq = builder.createTupleQuery();
// write the Root, Path elements as usual
Root<EntityClazz> root = cq.from(EntityClazz.class);
cq.multiselect(root.get(EntityClazz_.ID), root.get(EntityClazz_.VERSION));  //using metamodel
List<Tuple> tupleResult = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
for (Tuple t : tupleResult) {
    Long id = (Long) t.get(0);
    Long version = (Long) t.get(1);
}
```

Another approach is possible if you have a class representing the result, like `T` in your case. `T` doesn't need to be an Entity class. If `T` has a constructor like:

```
public T(Long id, Long version)
```

then you can use `T` directly in your `CriteriaQuery` constructor:

```
CriteriaQuery<T> cq = builder.createQuery(T.class);
// write the Root, Path elements as usual
Root<EntityClazz> root = cq.from(EntityClazz.class);
cq.multiselect(root.get(EntityClazz_.ID), root.get(EntityClazz_.VERSION));  //using metamodel
List<T> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

See this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/) for further reference.

Comment: How is EntityClazz_.VERSION accessed? Is it to suppose be some Enum?

Answer (score 16):

```
cq.select(cb.construct(entityClazz.class, root.get("ID"), root.get("VERSION")));  // HERE IS NO ERROR
```

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Criteria#Constructors

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't really see why you would want an object having only ID and Version, and all other props to be nulls. However, here is some code which will do that for you (which doesn't use JPA Em, but normal Hibernate. I assume you can find the equivalence in JPA or simply obtain the Hibernate Session obj from the em delegate
[Accessing Hibernate Session from EJB using EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335570/accessing-hibernate-session-from-ejb-using-entitymanager)
):

```
List<T> results = session.createCriteria(entityClazz)
    .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
        .add( Property.forName("ID") )
        .add( Property.forName("VERSION") )
    )
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(entityClazz); 
    .list();
```

This will return a list of Objects having their ID and Version set and all other props to null, as the aliasToBean transformer won't be able to find them. Again, I am uncertain I can think of a situation where I would want to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I want to use it in my webservice. Client requests list of "something" containing just IDs and Versions. Then he compares it to the cache, and requests full objects that changed. Sounds reasonable?

Comment: Is it to save network bandwidth? It is data dependent, I assume, but if you expect your data to change often, you could be wasting more bandwidth due to tcp/ip overhead of creating two requests than saving from just sending 'hollow' copies. Maybe it is worth checking out?

Comment: Yes, I know. I am going to use it only for data that will not change so often.

Comment: Well I could not find anything similar in JPA 2 :/

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like this

```
Session session = app.factory.openSession();
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery();
Root<Users> root = query.from(Users.class);
query.select(root.get("firstname"));
String name = session.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
```

where you can change "firstname" with the name of the column you want.