# JPA, Entity manager, select many columns and get result list custom objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

How I can get list of custom objects, like results below query:

```
SELECT p.category.id, count(p.id) FROM Product p left join p.category c WHERE p.seller.id=:id GROUP BY c.id
```

By example:

```
return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT p.category.id, count(p.id) FROM Product p left join p.category c WHERE p.seller.id=:id GROUP BY c.id").setParameter("id", id).getResultList();
```

I need a map with category id and number of products in category.

Comment: i recommend check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12702437/1211174). this answer has two examples 1. using tuples 2. using a class and generics

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Unfortunately, JPA doesn't provide a standard way to retrieve the results in a `Map`. However, building up your map manually by walking through the result list is simple enough:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = getEntityManager().createQuery(
    "SELECT c.id, count(p.id) " +
    "FROM Product p LEFT JOIN p.category c " +
    "WHERE p.seller.id = :id " +
    "GROUP BY c.id", Object[].class).setParameter("id", id);

List<Object[]> resultList = q.getResultList();
Map<String, Long> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Long>(resultList.size());
for (Object[] result : resultList)
  resultMap.put((String)result[0], (Long)result[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using hibernate(tagged), can try the below HQL query, I haven't tested.

`SELECT new map(p.category.id as category_id, count(p.id) as id_count) FROM Product p left join p.category c WHERE p.seller.id=:id GROUP BY c.id`

Comment: I just used tested this myself on a custom object created from a custom join query and it worked. I have a list of objects with keys rather than numeric indexes. The order is not preserved, but that doesn't matter since we have named indexes to grab with...

Answer (score -1):

Using JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink impl

For the first question: list of custom objects(no table objects):

**answer:** create a custom model and use the @Entity and @Id

```
@Entity
public class QueryModelDTO implements Serializable{ 
    @Id
    private Integer categoryId;
    private int count;
    ---gets and sets
}
```

create the query and execute

```
QueryModelDTO qm = (QueryModelDTO) em.createQuery(
                "SELECT p.category.id as categoryId, count(p.id) as count FROM Product p
                left join p.category c WHERE p.seller.id=:id 
                GROUP BY c.id",QueryModelDTO.class)
                .setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
```

For the second: how to read the response on a map

**answer:** Use the QueryHints and ResultTypes (this is one variant for the @DannyMo answer)

```
Query q  = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Foo f");
q.setHint(QueryHints.RESULT_TYPE, ResultType.Map);
List<Map> lm = q.getResultList();
    for (Map map : lm) {
        for (Object entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry<DatabaseField, Object> e = (Map.Entry<DatabaseField, Object>) entry;
            DatabaseField key = e.getKey();
            Object value = e.getValue();
            log.debug(key+"="+value);
        }            
    }
```

I hope this helps