# Typed query exception

Tags: java, maven, jpa

I am new in maven and java. I am developing a maven project and I want to select some data with multiple rows from mysql DB.
the following code has copied from below link. but it does not work. I have searched a lot and found some same results. but none of them works. I have no idea how can I do that.

[JPA, Entity manager, select many columns and get result list custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202334/jpa-entity-manager-select-many-columns-and-get-result-list-custom-objects)

my code:

```
try{
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.mycompany_LinkedIn_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU");
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
TypedQuery<KarjooSearchInfo[]> q = em.createQuery(" SELECT name,education,gender,more,time FROM karjoo_search_info WHERE 1 ", KarjooSearchInfo[].class);
List<KarjooSearchInfo[]> resultList = q.getResultList();
do something...
}catch....
```

the exception is:

```
An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [ SELECT name,education,gender,more,time FROM `karjoo_search_info` WHERE 1 ]. 
 [69, 69] An identification variable must be provided for a range variable declaration.
 [75, 76] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that your query is actually in JPQL, not SQL, so you are searching against managed classes -- not tables.

I think you may want:

```
TypedQuery<KarjooSearchInfo[]> q = em.createQuery("SELECT K FROM KarjooSearchInfo K", KarjooSearchInfo.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following changes:

- Trim off the leading blanks from the SQL.
- The class for the return objects should be `KarjooSearchInfo.class` instead of `KarjooSearchInfo[].class`.
- The condition should be `WHERE true` instead of `WHERE 1`.

Comment: tnx for your answer. but your solution did not work!!

Comment: createQuery takes in JPQL. It does NOT take in SQL.