# How to query a database table for a list of record with only two data objects

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

My database table looks like:

```
ID      ACCESSID    ENTITYGUID      NAME    NAMEID      OWNERGUID   TIMECREATED     VALUEID     VALUETYPE
```

I want to only retrieve a list with two fields, `name` AND `valueId`, not the whole record. I'm attempting this as follows:

via projections:

```
public void getAllEntityMetadata(int GUID) {
        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(RevMetadata.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("entityGUID", GUID))
                .setProjection(Projections.property("name"))
                .setProjection(Projections.property("nameId"));

        List<RevMetadata> m = (List<RevMetadata>) (RevMetadata) c.list();
        for (RevMetadata item : m) {
            System.out.println("-> All entity metadata for GUID: " + item.getName() + " : " + item.getValueId());
        }
}
```

I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to wakiliproject.Persistence.RevMetadata
    at wakiliproject.Persistence.PersistRevMetadata.getAllEntityMetadata(PersistRevMetadata.java:112)
    at wakiliproject.HomeController.showMetastring(HomeController.java:492)
    ... 40 more
```

Via query by example, I'm only getting the output below but no data. No error gets called:

```
public void getAllEntityMetadataEg(int GUID) {
        RevMetadata m = new RevMetadata();
        m.setEntityGUID(GUID);
        Example e = Example.create(m);

        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(RevMetadata.class).add(e);
        for (Iterator it = c.list().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            RevMetadata item = (RevMetadata) it.next();
            System.out.println("-> All entity metadata for GUID: " + item.getName() + " : " + item.getValueId());
        }
}
```

The output:

```
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_4_0_, this_.accessId as accessId2_4_0_, this_.entityGUID as entityGU3_4_0_, this_.name as name4_4_0_, this_.nameId as nameId5_4_0_, this_.ownerGUID as ownerGUI6_4_0_, this_.timeCreated as timeCrea7_4_0_, this_.valueId as valueId8_4_0_, this_.valueType as valueTyp9_4_0_ from METADATA this_ where (this_.accessId=? and this_.entityGUID=? and this_.nameId=? and this_.ownerGUID=? and this_.timeCreated=? and this_.valueId=?)
```

None of the approaches work. Please help me make it work so that I can get a list with two data objects of `name` and `nameId`

Update:

The database table entity class:

```
public class RevMetadata implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int valueId;

}
```

Comment: So you want to do a SELECT name, valueId from METADATA?

Comment: Yes, exactly, @mylenereiners, but be able to make it work via Hibernate's Criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only some specified columns will be retrieved, the result will be `List<Object[]>`.

In your case, `Object[]` will be populated with **`name` value => index 0** and **`nameId` => index 1**. Need to cast it to target value's type.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(RevMetadata.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("entityGUID", GUID));

criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("name"))
                        .add(Projections.property("nameId")));

List<Object[]> criteriaResult = criteria.list();

List<RevMetadata> results = new ArrayList<RevMetadata>();
//then get result into the class properties
for (Object[] object : criteriaResult) {
    //cast to target value type
    String name = (String)object[0];
    int nameId = ((Integer)object[1]).intValue();

    RevMetadata result = new RevMetadata();
    result.setName(name);
    result.setValueId(nameId);

    results.add(result);
}

//now results of List<RevMetadata> is ready
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Wundwin Born. I really can't thank you enough. That was so insightful. Thanks

Comment: @user3663765 Welcome and glad to hear it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

The projections needs to be added to projectList if you want to get multiple columns:

```
Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("name"))
.add(Projections.property("valueId"))
```

Also the `c.list()` returns a `List` and this list contains the fields added to your `projection list` so it contains an `object array` with first field as your `name` property and second field as your `valueId` property. So your `c.list()` should be like:

```
List<Object[]> rows = (List<Object[]>) c.list();
```

So here are the changes that works:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(RevMetadata.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("entityGUID", GUID));

        c.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.property("name"))
                .add(Projections.property("valueId")));

        List<Object[]> rows = (List<Object[]>) c.list(); 
        System.out.println(rows);
        for (Object[] row : rows) {
            System.out.println(row[0] + " and " + row[1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List m = c.list();
    for(Iterator it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext()) {
        Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
        System.out.println("-> All entity metadata for GUID: " + row[0] + " : " +row[1]);
    }
```

Comment: I did that but now I get the error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to wakiliproject.Persistence.RevMetadata
    at wakiliproject.Persistence.PersistRevMetadata.getAllEntityMetadata(PersistRevMetadata.java:114)

That is at the line:

    for (RevMetadata item : m) {

Still not working!

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.

Comment: I tried your edited response, but still no success. I get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

Comment: Integer[] row =  it.next();

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Problem is the double casting

```
(List<RevMetadata>) (RevMetadata) c.list();
```

Try to remove the cast

```
(RevMetadata)
```

Comment: I did that but now I get the error:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to wakiliproject.Persistence.RevMetadata
    at wakiliproject.Persistence.PersistRevMetadata.getAllEntityMetadata(PersistRevMetadata.java:114)

That is at the line:

    for (RevMetadata item : m) {

Still not working!

Comment: It seems that you have a general problem. see for dirrent query solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618489/jpa-criteria-api-select-only-specific-columns