# Is there a simple way to just select entity's id using criteria query?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, jpql

JPQL makes this kind of change very easy:

```
Select o from Orders as o where....

Select o.id from Orders as o where....
```

But in Criteria Query:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = kem.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Orders> query = builder.createQuery(Orders.class);
Root<Order> orders= query.from(Orders.class);
query.select(orders);
....
```

It looks that the select item is defined by builder.createQuery(Order.class) already without any flexibility.

I know we can use Tuple.class, but other than like is there any better way to just extra id(just one field) from a complicated query? Without such feature criteria query becomase very lack of flexibility.

Comment: I think you could query for a Tuple object as per this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618489/jpa-criteria-api-select-only-specific-columns

Comment: @Petros Splinakis Thanks but the problem here is we have to iterate all result to extract the only field value. Select<Tuple> only return a collection of Objects. There is no option to select a single field and get the result list directly like in the JPQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it can be done with the optional JPA Metamodel API, it can even be done using the plain Criteria API itself.

> It looks that the select item is defined by builder.createQuery(Order.class) already without any flexibility.

If you want to select the `id` of an order, then you shouldn't use `createQuery(Order.class)`, because that could cause the result to be an order instead of an `id` of an order. You should use the format `createQuery(ResultType.class)`. So if the `id` is for example a Java `Long`, then you should use `createQuery(Long.class)`.

So instead of this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = kem.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Orders> query = builder.createQuery(Orders.class);
Root<Order> orders = query.from(Orders.class);
query.select(orders);
....
```

It should be:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = kem.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<Order> orders = query.from(Orders.class);
query.select("id"); // or query.select(orders.get("id"))
....
```

You can even navigate using path navigation:

```
query.select(orders.get("customer").get("address").get("streetNumber"));
```

Answer (score 7):

The [JPA Metamodel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html) can be used for this.

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = builder.createQuery(String.class);
Root<Order> root = query.from(Orders.class);
query.select(root.get(Orders_.id));
```

Here, `Orders_` is the metamodel class for the `Orders` entity.

Comment: Thanks. So in such situation it is better to create metaModel class for the entity class? Also is it ok if I only place only id field in the metaModel class?

Comment: Sure, if it just one class you could take that approach.  Alternatively, you could look at using metamodel generators that would automatically generate the metamodel classes for you.

Comment: The generator should generate classes in the binary code, so I bet it would generate the actual code. Then how can we avoid the errors by IDE(Eclipse may complaint about the class does not exist)

Comment: Not necessarily.  Some generators generate the source code for the metamodel classes just before the compilation stage.  Sometimes you have control over where these classes are generated.  You can add the generation location to your Eclipse project classpath.  If this doesn't work for you, you can always generate the metamodel classes manually.  In any case, your original question has been answered as Eclipse errors were not part of your original question.  You should try the proposed solution and if you run into errors specific to the IDE you are using, you should raise a separate question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the instructions !