# Why does JPA TypedQuery throw Exception: Parameter value [...] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character]?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have searched through similar questions and found none helpful for this particularly weird problem of mine. The Exception message seems understandable, but a sensible reference to it's cause and where to make the appropriate corrections still beats me... I'm like ***WHY is the expected Type java.lang.Character???***

I have a `HashMap<String, Object>` called `params` that holds all the search parameters that i need to use to filter results of a query to a MySQL Database, so here's how I build my query using JPA Criteria API.

The aim is to search all the specified `dbColumns` for a String passed as the argument called `search`

```
List<String> dbColumns = Arrays.asList("firstname", "lastname", "username", "email", "mobilenumber", "dateJoined");

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Client> cq = cb.createQuery(Client.class);
Root<Client> entity = cq.from(Client.class);
cq.select(entity);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if(params.containsKey("search") && StringUtils.isNotBlank(search)){
    String search = String.valueOf(params.get("search"));
    for(String column : dbColumns){
        predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(entity.get(column).as(String.class)), "%"+search.toLowerCase()+"%")); 
    }
}

cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery(cq); //<--- Error gets thrown here
return query.getResultList();
```

However I keep getting this error. **Parameter value [%tunji%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character]** at this line `TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery(cq);`

Please see StackTrace snippet below;

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%tunji%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Character]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.validateParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:370) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:343) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:370) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:194) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler.compile(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:247) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:622) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.createQuery(AbstractEntityManager.java:96) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
```

This actually confuses me because i'm NOT making any reference to `java.lang.Character` at any point. Also all the MySQL columns except `dateJoined` are of type VARCHAR which should map to java's **`String`** Type.

The dbColumn `dateJoined` is of MySQL type DATETIME hence why I used `entity.get(column).as(String.class)` so that the String representation of the date will be compared with the `search` String.

So i'm wondering what may be the cause of this error and how best to go about solving this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

> **EDIT:**

In response to @Ish... Here's what the `Client` entity looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name="client")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Client.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Client c")
})
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length=255)
    private String email;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(length=20)
    private String mobilenumber;

    @Column(unique=true, length=255)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="datejoined")
    private Date dateJoined;

    //... getters ... and ... setters
}
```

Comment: it might help if you also post you code on the Client entity showing its mappings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some good experimenting with various strategies, here's what I did that finally worked.

Thanks to leads from this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618489/jpa-criteria-api-select-only-specific-columns?answertab=active#tab-top) that made me remember the JPA [`Tuple`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Tuple.html) Interface which essentially is an Object that can return multiple result Type(s). So to perform my `like` comparison, and since Date cannot be simply cast to a String here are the steps;

1. I get the column as a `Tuple`
2. do a check on The Tuple Object to see if it's assignable from Date
3. if it is, then get the Date-Format expression and pass it to the `like` expression.

Now, this is what I have replaced my former code with and works beautifully;

```
List<String> dbColumns = Arrays.asList("firstname", "lastname", "username", "email", "mobilenumber", "dateJoined");

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Client> cq = cb.createQuery(Client.class);
Root<Client> entity = cq.from(Client.class);
cq.select(entity);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if(params.containsKey("search") && StringUtils.isNotBlank(search)){
    String search = String.valueOf(params.get("search"));
    List<Predicate> ORPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    for(String column : dbColumns){
        Path<Tuple> tuple = entity.<Tuple>get(column);
        if(tuple.getJavaType().isAssignableFrom(Date.class)){
            Expression<String> dateStringExpr = cb.function("DATE_FORMAT", String.class, entity.get(column), cb.literal("'%d/%m/%Y %r'"));
            ORPredicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(dateStringExpr), "%"+search.toLowerCase()+"%"));
        }else{
            ORPredicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(entity.get(column).as(String.class)), "%"+search.toLowerCase()+"%")); 
        }
    }
    predicates.add(cb.or(ORPredicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
}

cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
TypedQuery<Client> query = em.createQuery(cq); //<--- Error gets thrown here
return query.getResultList();
```

**NOTE-WORTHY CONSIDERATIONS** -

1. I am aware that from wherever the search would be initiated, all my Dates are presented in this form `07/10/2015 10:25:09 PM` hence my ability to know how to format the Date for the comparison in my `like` expression as `"'%d/%m/%Y %r'"`.
2. This is just one step that works for Dates. Most other Types e.g int, long, char ...etc... can all be directly Cast to String and as I explore more Types of data, I'll definitely do the same for any other Type that cannot be directly Cast to String.

Though this works perfectly for me, I'll still keep it open for comments by anyone that may have any reservations about my strategy and I'll only mark it as the correct answer after I've subjected it to many more extensive tests.

And if this helps you out in any way... Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

Date cannot be cast to a String. See [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.1.0.Final/org/hibernate/ejb/AbstractQueryImpl.java#370). Your understanding about [Expression.as()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as(java.lang.Class)) method is not what's happening in reality.

Comment: @Frank, do you have an idea how to also search the the `dateJoined` column for the `search` String still using the JPA criteria API?

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve is using a SQL function on the RDB side. So I would do something like this: cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, root.get(column),cb.literal("'%d/%m/%Y'"). .

Comment: errr @Franck Thanks, very useful comment. But remember I pointed that my database was MySQL?... I'm sure what you actually meant was "DATE_FORMAT"...  cos if my memory hasn't failed me, "TO_CHAR" is an Oracle function.

Comment: you're absolutely right...but now you see how using this kind of specific db function defeats the whole purpose of the abstraction offered by jpa...If you don't have any other choice then you might use it as long as you remember what you're doing if you have to migrate to another rdb.

Comment: You have my upvote for that JPA abstraction comment @Frank!... I'll do well to appropriately document those areas!

Comment: I would have prefered an upvote on the answer  to get some points!

Comment: Ok, actually you very well deserve it... Yours was the first pointer that set me in the right direction. So there you have it.