# In JPA, is there a DB agnostic way to check if a table exists?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm wondering if there's a db agnostic way to check if a certain table exists in JPA (specifically, eclipse link).  Right now the way we do it is with a native query like this:

```
select count(*) from table_name where 1=2
```

If this throws an exception, we know the table doesn't exist.  And, as far as I know, this will work on most SQL databases.  The thing I don't is it's a hacky query and it throws a SQL exception when the table doesn't exist.  I'd prefer to be able to do a query that returns a `true`/`false` instead of a `no error`/`error`. But the only way I know how to do that is to query data dictionaries, and that won't be database agnostic.

In JPA, is there a DB agnostic way to check if a table exists?

Comment: What's configuring the underlying connection (java.sql.Connection)?

You should be able to get to it, get a connection, and then do connection.getMetaData().  That'll return an instance of DatabaseMetaData, which has a getTables() method.  It'll return a ResultSet that you can then scan.

Comment: @JoeRinehart I can only guess that JPA is.  I'll see if your suggestion works.  This documents how to get it in JPA: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3497206/61624

Comment: @tieTYT I've use that unwrapped mechanism before with JPA, it has worked for me in the past. For most DB implementations `getTables()` works correctly but I ran into an issue with the Teradata driver. For some reason `getTables()` didn't work correctly and basically never came back. As long as the driver implements `getTables()` correctly you should be good to go using JoeRinehart's suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I'll raise [Joe Rinehart's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1153778/joe-rinehart) comment to answer level. Using DatabaseMetaData.getTables() helped me query a table's existence in a mostly agnostic way without raising errors. A couple of comments.

1. getTables may have issues, for example with Teradata as pointed out by [Durandal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772385/durandal).
2. The resulting table names case is database dependent. For example, PostgreSQL converts to lower case by default whereas H2 converts to upper case by default.

A more agnostic method is to define a count method in a repository, such as the following (where Todo class is a JPA entity).

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends Repository<Todo, Long> {
    Long count();
}
```

The above is agnostic but will throw errors which must be caught, as shown below.

```
private long countTodos() {
    try {
        return todoRepository.count();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().info("Count error: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Errors will also show up in the log when no table is present.

```
2016-08-04 12:02:11.190  INFO 5788 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-04 12:02:11.296  WARN 5788 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42102, SQLState: 42S02
2016-08-04 12:02:11.296 ERROR 5788 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table "TodosTable_name" not found; SQL statement:
select count(*) as col_0_0_ from "TodosTable_name" todo0_ [42102-192]
2016-08-04 12:02:11.303  INFO 5788 --- [           main] c.s.e.SpringJpaDemoApplicationTests      : Count error: could not prepare statement; SQL [select count(*) as col_0_0_ from "TodosTable_name" todo0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Comment: Won't the Repository solution throw an error on startup?  It seems like an entity without a table.