# How to get all column names of table in Spring data

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, database-metadata

I am using mysql, spring boot, spring data .... :D
I am searching for solution to get all column names of a given table. But could not found as per my requirnments :(

Not want a solution with native query or mysql specific solution.
Looking for general solution using spring data abstraction.

If there is any derived method query then it would be great.

thank you :)

Comment: for what do you need the column names? For entity generation?

Comment: not entity generation. for formula attributes. Is there any solution?

Comment: No. You can probably do either using either the JPA Meta Model or by getting a handle on the underlying Connection and querying  the DatabaseMetaData. For the former create a custom repo which will give you a refererence to the EntityManager and then get the connection from this (how will depend on your JPA provider).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any Simplest way to get Table metadata (column name list) information, in Spring Data JPA ? which could I use on universal database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239812/is-there-any-simplest-way-to-get-table-metadata-column-name-list-information)