# How to get column names of a table using spring data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot, spring data JPA, I am searching for solution to get all column names of a given table. But could not found as per my requirements

Not want a solution with native query.Looking for general solution using spring data abstraction.

I am able to get the column names using normal java but i want to fetch them using spring data JPA.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239812/is-there-any-simplest-way-to-get-table-metadata-column-name-list-information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any Simplest way to get Table metadata (column name list) information, in Spring Data JPA ? which could I use on universal database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239812/is-there-any-simplest-way-to-get-table-metadata-column-name-list-information)

Answer (score 3):

**they are several ways**

```
public interface TableMetadataRepository extends JpaRepository<TableMetadata, TableMetadataKey>
{
  TableMetadata findByTableName(String tableName);
}
```

then you can go for

```
List<TableMetadata> metadata = tableMetadataRepository.findAll()
TableMetadata metadataofspecifictable = tableMetadataRepository.findByTableName("urtable");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, do I need to create TableMetadata class?

Comment: yes you need to create TableMetadata class to  hold metadata information