# How to get the postgresql column names in java springboot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to get the postgresql table column name. I've tried using information_schema but it doesn't work on my java mvc project. What should I do ?

This is actually my first question on StackOverflow, so I'm sorry if my question is difficult to understand. Thank you!

```
public interface MyFileRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntityModel, Long> {
    @Query("select column_name,data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'MyEntityModel';")
    List<MyEntityModel> myList();
}
```

Comment: You could have a look at the link here https://stackoverflow.com/q/36328063/5891534

Answer (score 0):

About schema. You can set default schema by two ways:

1. Put it to the properties(or .yml file) `spring.datasource.schema = #your schema name`
2. Put it in your entity model `@Table(schema = "SCHEMA_NAME")`

About getting information about table you can look this one open question:

[Is there any Simplest way to get Table metadata (column name list) information, in Spring Data JPA ? which could I use on universal database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239812/is-there-any-simplest-way-to-get-table-metadata-column-name-list-information)