# How to obtain the connection string from javax.persistence.EntityManger

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

How can I get the current connection string or connection from javax.persistence.EntityManager?

The code I tried was

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
connection=entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
System.out.print(connection.toString());
```

persistence.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" > 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence>  
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Hibernate_SQLServer" transaction-type = > 
     "RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.dal.es.sqldatabase.dto.AssetDto</class>
    <class>com.dal.es.sqldatabase.dto.CasinoDto</class>  

    <properties>
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://xx.x.xxx.xxx\\sql2012:1433;databaseName=Casino" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="abc@1234" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
   <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" /
  </properties>
```

The unwrap method throws a Hibernate cannot unwrap interface java.sql.Connection exception.

I tried the solution posted in the link below, but was not successful in obtaining the connection string.
  [Getting Database connection in pure JPA setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493495/getting-database-connection-in-pure-jpa-setup)

Comment: are you using hibernate?

Comment: Not directly. I use org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

Comment: use entityManager.unwrap(Session.class) where Session is hibernate's session class. This would give you back the hibernate's session.

Comment: @Indu did the solution given in my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can not `unwrap` `Connection` object from `entityManager`, what you need to do is `unwrap` `Session` object first and then get `Connection` using `Work` API.

Below code snippet does exactly the same.

```
Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).doReturningWork(conn -> conn);
try {
    DatabaseMetaData metaData = connection.getMetaData();
    String url = metaData.getURL();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Since you need connection string, you can get it from `Metadata`.