# How to change isolation level for a transaction of Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

Can the isolation level be changed per transaction if using Hibernate?

I want to add it to the following code:

```java
int num = entityManager.createNamedQuery("deleteUserInfo")
    .setParameter("userId", userId).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Are you running on Spring?

Comment: No. I'm not using Spring.

Comment: https://www.waitingforcode.com/hibernate/transaction-isolation-in-hibernate/read

Comment: According to this document, I understand that the isolation level can be changed per system but cannot be changed per transaction. Do you also think so?

Comment: "Normally, the isolation level is set at java.sql.Connection level, through setTransactionIsolation(int level) method".  I think that means you can change it whenever you want to

Comment: Umm.. I Don't know how to get `java.sql.Connection` from `EntityManager`.

Comment: hmm, I always get it from the datasource, or the connection pool.  Maybe this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493495/getting-database-connection-in-pure-jpa-setup

Comment: @djb Thank you for your comment! I will check it.